# join 2 tables and get some columns from 1st table and max timestamp value from second table

Tags: sql, join, db2, max, left-join

I have a employee table

```
empid empname status
1     raj     active
2     ravi    active
3     ramu    active
4     dan     active
5     sam     inactive
```

I have another table called facilities

```
empid timestamp
1     2014-12-28 
1     2015-05-05 
1     2015-06-05 
2     2015-05-03 
2     2015-06-04 
3     2015-02-01
```

I want my result like

```
empid empname status lastusedts
1     raj     active 2015-06-05
2     ravi    active 2015-06-04
3     ramu    active 2015-02-01
4     dan     active null
```

So i have to join my employee table and facilities table and find when the employee has last used the facilities by getting the max of time stamp and for employees who did not use it the timestamp value should be null and only active employees are to be fetched.
Please help me in writing this query in db2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a `LEFT JOIN` with a `GROUP BY` to find the `MAX`(timestamp):

```
select e.empid, e.empname, e.status, max(timestamp) as lastusedts
from employee e
  left join facilities f on e.empid = f.empid
where e.status = 'active'
group by e.empid, e.empname, e.status
```

Alternatively, a correlated sub-select for the max-timestamp:

```
select e.empid, e.empname, e.status, (select max(timestamp) from facilities f
                                      where e.empid = f.empid) as lastusedts
from employee e
where e.status = 'active'
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT employee.empid, employee.empname, employee.status,facilities.timestamp as lastusedts
FROM employee
INNER JOIN facilities
ON employee.empid=facilities.empid;
```

Comment: but i want the max of timestamp (that is when the user has last used the facilities), and if he has not used the facilities at all i should get null value and i should fetch only active employee recorde

Comment: SELECT employee.empid, employee.empname, employee.status, 

max(facilities.timestamp as lastusedts)

FROM employee

INNER JOIN facilities

ON employee.empid=facilities.empid

and employee.status = 'active'

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT e.empid, e.empname, e.status, MAX(f.timestamp) AS lastusedts 
 FROM employee e LEFT OUTER JOIN facilities f ON e.empid = f.empid 
 WHERE e.status = 'active' GROUP BY e.empid, e.empname, e.status
```

Comment: Please consider adding more textual details to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Common table expressions [CTE's] are one way you can break a problem down into easier chunks.

```
with m as
(
  select empid
        ,max(timestamp) as lastusedts
    from facilities
    group by e.empid
)
select e.empid
      ,e.empname
      ,e.status
      ,m.lastusedts
  from employee e
  left join  m 
     on e.empid = m.empid
  where e.status = 'active'
```

Answer (score 0):

Common table expressions [CTE's] are one way you can break a problem down into easier chunks.

```
with m as
(
  -- get last timestamp per employee
  select empid
        ,max(timestamp) as lastusedts
    from facilities
    group by e.empid
)
-- report employee info with last timestamp
select e.empid
      ,e.empname
      ,e.status
      ,m.lastusedts
  from employee e
  left join  m 
     on e.empid = m.empid
  where e.status = 'active'
```